# Is there a better way to count the number of columns equal a certain value based on an ID?

Tags: r, data.table

Here's what I figured out:

```
library(data.table)    
blah.dt[ , count:= table(as.matrix(.SD))[names(table(as.matrix(.SD)))=="0"] , by =  ID]
```

Just wondering if there is a better or faster way to do this operation using data.table because I'm sure there is

Comment: Can you elaborate on your input and required output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I get what you want: you have a data.table, and for each ID you want to know the total number of zeroes in all those columns.

In that case, we could do something like:

```
dat[, count:=sum(.SD==0),by=ID]
```

This has the advantage that it returns a count of 0 with no zeroes present, instead of missing.

(With some dummy data):

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.table(X1=sample(0:3,10,T),
                  X2=sample(0:3,10,T),
                  ID=sample(LETTERS[1:2],10,T))

dat[, count:=sum(unlist(.SD)==0),by=ID]
dat[, count2:=table(as.matrix(.SD))[names(table(as.matrix(.SD)))=="0"], by = ID, .SDcols=c("X1","X2")] # to check

dat[,table(count==count2)]
TRUE 
  10
```

Comment: Ah makes so much sense. I forget sometime how easy it is in R to compare things. Thanks